# How can I import my html files into my Google Sites page?

Tags: html, google-sites-2016

The best I can do so far is to embed code from just one html file. On the preview page, I get a scrollable box taking up half the page that contains my desired output, surrounded by white space. Rather, I would prefer my page take up the entire page, if that makes any sense.

(In the end, I decided to create my site on Git Hub instead because it lets me directly post my HTML files.)

Comment: Are you using the old or the new Google Sites?

Comment: New, as far as I know.